# coin change - all solutions recursive - Java

Tags: java, recursion

I am trying to find all possible to solutions to the [coin change problem](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-7-coin-change/).

Example: I have the coins 1 and 2 available and I want to change 6.

**Right Solution:** [1,1,1,1,1,1], [2,1,1,1,1,0], [2,2,1,1,0,0], ...

**My Code:** [1,1,1,1,1,1], [1,1,1,1,0,0], [1,1,0,0,0,0], ...

The last line also deletes my parameter "coinsSoFar" and I don't understand why. When I debug it sets temp to [0,0,0,0,0,0] AND coinsSoFar to [0,0,0,0,0,0], which should stay at [2,0,0,0,0,0].

Would be very thankful for help.
(clearArray: all numbers set to 0; addToArray: replace first 0 with number)

```
    public static void makeChange(int amount, int startCoinIndex, int[] coinsSoFar) {

    if (amount == 0) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(coinsSoFar));
    }

    if (startCoinIndex == coinSet.length || amount < 0) {return;}

    for (int i = 0; i * coinSet[startCoinIndex] <= amount; i++) {

        int[] temp = coinsSoFar;

        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            addToArray(temp, coinSet[startCoinIndex]);
        }

        makeChange(amount - i * coinSet[startCoinIndex], startCoinIndex+1, temp);
        clearArray(temp);  // this line also clears coinsSoFar. Why?

    }
}
```

Comment: You clear original array with the `clearArray(temp, 0)` - pass by reference. calling `int[] temp = coinsSoFar;` you don't create a copy of the array but a reference to the same array. Also should be `|| amount <= 0`

Comment: Thank you very much, with these two changes the function works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You clear original array with the `clearArray(temp, 0)` - pass by reference.

Calling `int[] temp = coinsSoFar;` you don't create a copy of the array but a reference to the same array.

Also should be `|| amount <= 0`

Answer (score 1):

When you do

```
int[] temp = coinsSoFar;
```

you are setting temp to reference the same array as `coinsSoFar`.  So anything you do to `temp` now affects `coinsSoFar`.

If you meant for `temp` to refer to a *copy* of `coinsSoFar`, here's what to do:

```
int[] temp = Arrays.copyOf(coinsSoFar, coinsSoFar.length);
//  OR, if you prefer
int[] temp = new int[coinsSoFar.length];
System.arraycopy(coinsSoFar, 0, temp, 0, coinsSoFar.length);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I thought of the reference as a copy.